Scan the string from white space until end using format specifier
I have an existing code that scans a string and stores values in multiple temporary variables.
Here is the sample code:
char str[] = "# # Time=80 interval";
char hash1, hash2;
char timeStr[20];

sscanf(str, "%c %c %[^\0]s", &hash1, &hash2, timeStr);

printf("hash 1: %c\n", hash1);
printf("hash 2: %c\n", hash2);
printf("Time String: %s\n", timeStr);

Actual output is:
hash 1: #
hash 2: #
Time String: 

The expected output is:
hash 1: #
hash 2: #
Time String: Time=80 interval

I modified the code and it is working:
sscanf(str, "%c %c **%[^\n]s**", &hash1, &hash2, timeStr);

This is legacy code %[^\0]s and it is not working now.
Can someone help to understand by any chance why it was working earlier and stopped working now?

What you need is regular expression, which are part of STL since C++11. And sscanf do not work with regular expression. So, if you do not stick intentionally to C++98, it is very simple in use and also portable https://cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

In this string literal you've embedded a \0:
"%c %c %[^\0]s"

What the scanf function will see is everything up to the \0, so it sees the format string
"%c %c %[^"

Some compilers may even complain about it and say "no closing ']' for '%[' format".
Furthermore, %[^\n]s should be just %[^\n]. %[...] and %s are different conversion specifiers. Also, always check the return value from scanf.

Can someone help to understand by any chance why it was working earlier and stopped working now?

The earlier compiler presumably treated the non-terminated %[^ sequence as %[^\0] to allow for mistakes like this, in which case you could probably just have used "%c %c %[^" with the old compiler. The new compiler does not support this extension.

BTW, escaping doesn't solve the issue neither Demo

Thanks @Ted,  Understood.  I'm not expecting new line in the input string. I just want to read all character till the end of string. Do you think [^\n] is correct choice. Earlier implementation seems [^\0] is specific to read all chars until it encounter the terminating character '\0'

@PriyankaChauhan If you stick with scanf, just use any character that is guaranteed to not be in the string. \n is often good but there are many others you could use. Personally, I'd drop scanf completely and use C++ std::strings and helper functions, like std::getline.

@Jarod42  No, that'd read everything up to the first \ or 0 :-)
